# Extjs4 iconCls can't display in symfony

Tags: symfony1, extjs4

I have a project which use Extjs4 and symfony.

I put extJS source code in symonfy's web/js folder and web/css.

**So i can load extjs like :**

```
 <?php
      use_stylesheet('ext/resources/css/ext-all.css');
 ?>
```

I created a formpanel and config the iconCls: 'icon-add' but it doesn't work in the page,the icon can't display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you test inside firebug and try to see what ressource ***symfony / extJS*** is trying to load, you'll maybe have a network error or something like that.

How do you declare your `icon-add` css class?

Comment: yeah,i don't define icon-add in css.